# How can I customize autocomplete view?

Tags: css, autocomplete, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, vue-component

My view like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q" autofocus v-model="typeahead" @input="input">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ref="submitButton"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
        </span>
        <ul v-if="!selected && typeahead">
            <li v-for="state in filteredStates" @click="select(state)">{{ state }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use vue.js

Demo and full code like this :
http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/tm8k8907/20/

If I input a keyword, the display becomes uncluttered like a demo in jsfiddle

I want autocomplete under input type search below :

[image]

How can I make it like autocomplete google?

I'm still newbew in css

Comment: I think you have misspelled `vue js autocomplete` as `macbook` while typing on google there.

Comment: @Nisarg Shah, Sorry my english is not good enough. But essentially I want my autocomplete view just like google autocomplete view

Comment: I meant to suggest that you should search for it on google. There are a LOT of libraries that support such features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap, you can just create two rows if you want the result to appear below the search as seen in this demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/samayo/tm8k8907/22/

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
     selected: null,
     typeahead: null,
      states: ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming']
    },
    computed:{
      filteredStates(){
        return this.states.filter(s => s.toLowerCase().includes(this.typeahead.toLowerCase()))
      }
    },
    
    methods: {
     select: function(state){
       this.typeahead = state
        this.selected = state
      },
      
      input: function(){
       this.selected = null
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.6/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="app">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q" autofocus v-model="typeahead" @input="input">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ref="submitButton"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <ul v-if="!selected && typeahead">
        <li v-for="state in filteredStates" @click="select(state)">{{ state }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I mean. But there are still shortcomings. How can I remove the bullet from ul and make the hover like autocomplete google? So the view same with the autocomplete google

Comment: If you want to remove the bullets from the ul, just add this style: `ul {list-style-type: none}` or check out the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/samayo/tm8k8907/23/ but i'm not sure what you mean "same view with the autocomplete" .. it is similar

Comment: Thanks. But there are still shortcomings. The hover is still not tidy. It was not docked to the left as hover google autocomplete. Try you see hover google autocomplete position. It's a little different

Comment: Thanks. I want to ask again. Is there any other way without create two rows? Because if I implement it to my actual project, it looks so unkempt

Comment: Yeah, maybe you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/samayo/tm8k8907/25/ by removing the rows.

Comment: Thanks for your help